# Trying to fill textbox via webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

Trying to send text to a textbox via webdriver,

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'input-description-2').send_keys(description)
```

doesnt work cause it said it can't find the id ,

i need to send the (description) variable to the textbox below is the snipet its market with aria-label the text below containing the word "test" is where it need to be send to,
What is the best way to tackle this?

```html
<body aria-label="Editor, input-description-2" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" contenteditable="true" aria-readonly="false" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" spellcheck="true"><p>test<br></p></body>
```

```
driver.find_element(By.ID).send_keys(description)
```

i tried it doing via the above but i probally need to specify it differently since its using aria-label?

i recorded with selenium the steps to edit the textbox

````
"id": "77055a56-462c-4d7d-931b-a8b804c11229",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "selectFrame",
      "target": "index=1",
      "targets": [
        ["index=1"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "6fc33a07-99f5-44e6-9334-d1b3f79c1d26",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "css=p",
      "targets": [
        ["css=p", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//p", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "aeafe709-e3b2-4198-9a2f-b4e69f9d3099",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "editContent",
      "target": "css=.cke_editable",
      "targets": [
        ["css=.cke_editable", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//body", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": "<p>test<br type=\"_moz\"></p>"
    }]```



how would i do the same steps but in python with the webdriver?
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **XPATH**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Using XPath to find the element by aria-label attribute
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body[@aria-label="Editor, input-description-2"]')

# Sending keys to the element
element.send_keys(description)
```

You can also try with **CSS_SELECTOR**

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Using CSS selector to find the element by aria-label attribute
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body[aria-label="Editor, input-description-2"]')

# Sending keys to the element
element.send_keys(description)
```

Comment: it seems it can't find the element with neither i tried both xpath method and CSS_selector

```im getting no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body[aria-label="Editor, input-description-2"]"}```

Comment: If I know the url , you are trying to scrap I could provide you the correct solution. @Phantom

Comment: https://demo.opencart.com/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product|form&user_token=65f86529fd41a3b87694d2e89813632f

the username is : demo password : demo aswel
 
its this textbox https://imgur.com/a/pdstSqC

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the description field seems 'hidden' and 'disabled'.

However, it seems that the ID of that field is "input-description-1", not "input-description-2".

Lastly, I wonder where you've found that **body** tag cause it doesn't look like a text area and I was unable to see something similar from the DOM.

Comment: like i said the above old script is for an older version of the website and things have changed, also the name is cause there is multiple languages

Comment: i think the DOM maybe only becomes visible if you type in it prehaps?